# Haskell: Let inside List comprehension unexpected result

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, let

I'm new to haskell and I am trying to learn haskell. I am trying to create simple functions like "duplicate" in the most possible ways i can think. I have already done "duplicate" with pattern matching and guards.
I can't get it working with a let inside a list comprehension.
I can imagine let inside a list comprehension is not ideally  but I am more interested why it does not work =].

My question is: why does duplicate' produces [Int] and duplicate'' produces [[Int]]
and is it even possible to produce [Int] with a let inside a list comprehension?

Thank you for your time and help :).

```
--list comprehension
duplicate' xs = [y | x <- xs, y <- [x,x]]
input => [1,2,3,4]
output => [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]
expected? => yes

--list comprehension with let
duplicate'' xs = [y | x <- xs, let y = [x,x]]
input => [1,2,3,4]
output => [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3],[4,4]]
expected? => yes
```

Comment: `[y | x <- xs, let y = [x,x]]` == `[[x,x] | x <- xs]` you see, it's not what you wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<-` and `let` simply mean different things.

When you write `y <- [x,x]`, you are saying "give `y` each of the values inside the list `[x,x]` in turn".

When you write `let y = [x,x]`, you are saying "give `y` the value `[x,x]`".

Answer (score 4):

`let` does nothing but define a new symbol to take one some given value. You could always just inline the definition by hand:

```
[ y | x <- xs, let y = [x,x] ] ≡ [ [x,x] | x <- xs ]
```

Any such expression with only one `<-` has thus the form

```
[ f x | x<-xs ]
```

which is equivalent to `map f xs`. So the result list must then always have the same length as `xs`, making the desired behaviour of `duplicate` impossible to achieve: if you want to have duplicates, you need to encapsulate them as inner lists so they won't count as more elements.

To merge these nested lists back into a "flat" one, you can utilise the fact that lists are a monad:

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

> Prelude Control.Monad> join [[1,1], [2,2]]
>   [1,1,2,2]

Now, `join` is in fact how category theorists prefer to define monads, but as you may know Haskell does it a bit differently:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
a >>= f = join (fmap f a)
```

or, as it is actually defined the other way around,

```
join a = a >>= id
```

Put that into the modified `let` version of `duplicate`:

```
join [y | x <- xs, let y = [x,x] ]
  ≡ [y | x <- xs, let y = [x,x] ] >>= id
  ≡ map (\x -> [x,x]) xs >>= id
  ≡ xs >>= id . (\x -> [x,x])
  ≡ xs >>= (\x -> [x,x])
  ≡ do { x<-xs; [x,x] }
  ≡ do { x<-xs; y<-[x,x]; return y }  -- by the monad laws
```

Now, an expression `do { a<-p; b<-q; ... return x }` is a *monad comprehension*, the generalisation of list comprehensions. It can be rewritten `[x | a<-q, b<-q, ...]`. For our problem,

```
join [y | x <- xs, let y = [x,x] ] ≡ [y | x<-xs, y<-[x,x]]
```

which is where you started. It is inevitable to use two `<-`s when doing this with a pure list comprehension.

Of course you could still use *also* a let, at any point...

```
[y | x<-xs, y<-[x,x]]
     ≡ [y | x<-xs, let z=[x,x], y<-z]
     ≡ [a | x<-xs, let z=[x,x], y<-z, let a=y]
     ≡ [a | x<-xs, let z=let w=[let q=x in q, let r=x in r] in w, y<-z, let a=y]
     ≡ ...
```

Comment: Do I get it right that concat is a specialised join for lists? (Or maybe the other way around: join for the list monad is implemented with concat?)

Comment: @kqr `join`(defined with `(>>=)` which is defined with `foldr` for `[a]`) and `concat`(is defined with `foldr`) are defined separately, but both do the same for lists.